# Passing multiple parameters between functions

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I am looking at the following design pattern:

```
x_min = minimize( 'f', x_initial, step_size, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 );
```

... where f is some function ...

```
function y = f( x, p1, p2, p3 )
    :
end
```

... for which `minimize` will attempt to find a local minimum:

```
function x_min = minimize( FUNC_NAME, x_initial, step_size, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 )
    X = x_initial;

    % compose string used to call function
    argstr = [FUNC_NAME, '(X']; 
    for i = 1:(nargin - 3)
        argstr = [argstr, ',p', int2str(i)];
    end
    argstr = [argstr, ')'];
    :
    x1 = eval( argstr ); % etc
    :
```

It is very ugly -- for a start it ties `eval( argstr )` to only executing `f` on `X`.

It's rather old code (dated 2001).

Is there a preferred way to handle this scenario nowadays?

Is there any way to accomplish this so that the implementation of f is at the call-site?  i.e. invisible to `minimize.m`?  The existing pattern requires it is in separate `f.m` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, [it is not recommended to use `eval`.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

If the number of input arguments is unknown and variable, you can include [`varargin`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) as an input argument and pass the [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) instead of the function name. `varargin` brings a flexible number of input arguments together as a cell array and passes them to the function:

```
function out = anyfun(func_handle, varargin)
out = func_handle(varargin{:})
```

As an example:

```
anyfun(@mod, 123, 100)

ans =

    23
```

For your example, you should define the function like:

```
function x_min = minimize(FUNC_handle, x_initial, step_size, varargin)
:
x1 = FUNC_handle(varargin{:});
:
```

Answer (score 2):

For executing f on X, you can use [Function Handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html).
Example: `f = @sin; f(pi/2)` results `ans = 1`.

For implementation of f at the call-site, you can use an [Anonymous Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Example:
Executing `minimize` for function f(x) = x^2:

```
x_initial = 1;
step_size = 0.01;
q = minimize(@(x) x.^2, x_initial, step_size);
```

minimize implementation example (simplified implementation of minimum finding):

```
function x_min = minimize(f, x_initial, step_size)
    X = x_initial-10:step_size:x_initial+10; %Prepare input array for f.
    Y = f(X);
    x_min = min(Y);
```

Comment: It's faster if you make an actual function, rather than an anonymous function.